# Avd and sdk manager is missing in Window option Eclipse

Tags: linux, eclipse, sdk

I am **not able to see the avd and sdk manager in eclipse in Linux 12.04**.How can i install it ?
At first when i set up the sdk it was installing due to error in network connection i closed the window while installing.Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it .In Eclipse -> Windows ->Customize Perspective -> Select Android SDK and AVD manager -> OK